# Laravel database insertion while using a JWT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rest, jwt

I'm trying to create an order requiring a bearer token. Here what I'm trying to do is, decoding the token's payload to get the user's ID who requested to create an order, and insert that ID to orders table's userId column .I'm having a hard time with this error which is "userId doesn't have a default value". These are my migrations

**Orders Table**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('orderCode');
            $table->bigInteger('userId')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->bigInteger('productId')->unsigned();;
            $table->foreign('productId')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->date('shippingDate');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    }
};
```

**Products Table**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
};
```

**Users Table**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

And this is the method in the controller that I'm trying to use:

```
public function createOrder(Request $request)
    {

        $token = $request->bearerToken();

        $credits = json_decode(base64_decode(str_replace('_', '/', str_replace('-', '+', explode('.', $token)[1]))));

        $user = (int)($credits->sub);


        $request->validate([
            'orderCode' => 'required|string|max:8',
            'productId' => 'required|integer',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer',
            'address' => 'required|string',
            'shippingDate' => 'required|date'
        ]);
        $productId = $request->productId;
        $quantity = $request->quantity;

        $myProduct = Product::find($productId);

        if (!$myProduct) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Product not found!'
            ], 404);
        } else {
            if ($myProduct->amount < $request->quantity) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'Invalid quantity (more than amount or negative)!'
                ], 400);
            } else {
                $order = Order::create([
                    'orderCode' => $request->orderCode,
                    'userId' => $user,
                    'productId' => $productId,
                    'quantity' => $quantity,
                    'address' => $request->address,
                    'shippingDate' => $request->shippingDate
                ]);

                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'message' => 'order created successfully',
                    'order' => $order
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error I'm having Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `orders` (`orderCode`, `productId`, `quantity`, `address`, `shippingDate`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ABC12345, 2, 500, Wall Street, 2022-12-12, 2022-09-01 09:56:43, 2022-09-01 09:56:43)) in file C:\Users\kamilcoban\Desktop\rest-api-task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 759

but I assign a value to $user, using the token. In users table IDs are bigint and unsigned. Is this declaration occuring the problem? Or I missing somewhere?

When I `dd($user)` it prints ^1 which is the userId

Comment: Can you dd($user); and post it here ?

Comment: @workservice it's defined as `$user = (int)($credits->sub);` so it's guaranteed to be an integer >= 0.

Comment: Your error message includes a stack trace that tells you exactly where the error condition is being triggered. That, along with some simple calls to `dd()`, should tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: what if $credits->sub is null?

Comment: @miken32 I did the dd($user)